# Can't pass props to IIFE in JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

I'm trying to use react-rails to create a UI for an existing rails app. I want to make a dynamic todo list which is populated with data from my rails backend. I'm passing the tasks to the component through an erb tag provided by the gem 'react-rails'. This should make the data available as a prop for me to use, but when I try to render it in the JSX, I get an

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
```

error message in the console for the line

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tasks.length; i++) {
```

Here's my code:

The React(rails) component

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card col-6">
        <div className="card-header">
          <div className="float-rights">
            create new button
         </div>
        </div>
       <div className="card-body">
          {
            (function(){
              var html;
             for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tasks.length; i++) {
                html += this.props.tasks[i]
              }
             return html;
            })()
         }
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
 }
```

The ERB/HTML view it's rendered in

```
 <%= react_component('TodoApp', tasks: @collaboration.tasks) %>
```

Ideally the loop would run and I would get some output.

Comment: Why exactly do you need an iife inside JSX? You can use the array `map`, also, in order to directly set html, you have to use a special syntax, you might want to consider sending json from the server.

Comment: Are you sure `this` inside of the iifee is not undefined?  It looks to me like it it should be undefined, I would use an arrow function to capture lexical this.

Comment: What is the point of an IIFE here?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Primarily as a container for the loop. After reading through some of these answers (@AvinKavish and @Amauri) I see that it's a bit unnecessary and that I should just use an array method.

Comment: Yep! i'd recommend going through [**react docs for lists and keys**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to get more info about best practices related to what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell, will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your IIFE working by binding `this` from the outer scope,

```
<div className="card-body">
    {
        (function(){
             var html;
             for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tasks.length; i++) {
                html += this.props.tasks[i]
              }
            return html;
         }).bind(this)()
     }
</div>
```

But this is not idiomatic React. The following is,

```
<div className="card-body">
    {this.props.tasks.join('')}
</div>
```

If the tasks are in html format as indicated by the name of the variable you have used,

```
<div className="card-body"
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: this.props.tasks.join('') } }>
</div>
```

With this approach you have to sanitize the tasks to prevent script injection and you also lose the benefits of react such as event binding. It is not recommended

Comment: Good answer @AvinKavish. Much more thorough explanation than mine :)

Comment: @bflemi3 yours also answered the core of my question, but I will give the nod to Avin incase someone else wants the depth of response.

Answer (score 2):

Your IIFE is a closure, so `this` is not the context you think it is. Try this...

```
<div className="card-body">
    {this.props.tasks.map(task => task)}
</div>
```

Although I'm not sure what `task` is... that's another problem you may need to fix. If you provide an explanation I will update my answer appropriately.